# Embedding other API resource in a WebAPI response

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api

In my current WebAPI design I am planning to allow the client (API consumer) to choose which linked resources should be included.

**The scenario I have is:**

```
GET /api/member/1
```

returns:

```
{
    "memberId": 1,
    "headshot": {
        "href": "http://localhost/api/member/1/photo/1",
        "id": 1
    },
    "photos": {
        "href": "http://localhost/api/member/1/photo"
    }
    ... more ...
}
```

So the default response includes a "link"to the desired resource. In this scenario, more than often the headshot is a common field that would be required often and can sound convoluted to have to be request the headshot details separately.

**What I would like to do is:**

```
GET /api/member/1?embedded=headshot
```

returns:

```
{
    "memberId": 1,
    "headshot": {
        "href": "http://localhost/api/member/1/photo/1",
        "id": 1,
        "large": "http://localhost/images/large/1.jpg",
        "thumb": "http://localhost/images/thumb/2.jpg",
        ... more ...
    },
    "photos": {
        "href": "http://localhost/api/member/1/photo"
    }
    ... more ...
}
```

**Question:**

What is the best/recommended way in WebAPI 2.2 to manipulate the response to "add" the additional fields that "embedding" the resource would require.

Any major flaws in this approach?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common performance improvement that is made by API implementors and is commonly called side loading. I'm going to guess that you're not following a specific "json api" standard, but you may get some inspiration from looking at one such as http://jsonapi.org.

As an API consumer, I would not be surprised to be able to specify the related resources to include using a query parameter.